# How does Damage over Time (DoT) interact with Centaur Warrunner's return skill?

Tags: dota-2

Centaur Warrunner has a passive ability, "Return":

> Centaur Warrunner immediately counters every attack, damaging the attacker based on a percentage of Centaur's strength.
>   Base Damage: 16/18/20/22
>   Bonus Damage as Percent of Centaur Warrunner's Strength: 26%/34%/42%/50%

Source: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Centaur_Warrunner

If an enemy hero uses a DoT ability, does Return activate on each instance of damage and do "returned" damage to the caster?

Comment: Could you quote the abilities in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centaur Warrunner's Return does only proc on attempted attacks and therefor does not return damage from skills including damage over time.

Furthermore damage from units (for example Venomancer's wards) wont trigger Return on the hero.

Comment: Like Axe Helix. And it proc even if you cancel your attack ==> you can suicide on centaur without attacking him once, pretty funny

Comment: that's why i wrote attempted. if you have autoattack on you can only evade the damage by moving

Comment: there was that furion farming on the hill in the enemy forest and centaur appeared. fury had autoattack on and the player stopped it all the time by pressing stop :) . So he triggered the return damage over 9000 times and died. nearly instanty^^